# How to "lower the resolution" of a lat long csv

Tags: data, csv

I have a csv with 12.5 million date/lat/long/value points, it's a point every 800 meters ( in a grid ) of the united states

what's the best way to convert the points to every 1600 meters? or 3200? etc...

Really need to reduce the file size

Comment: Wouldn't you rather retain the information by using a raster format, in which position is assumed (and therefore only stored with the upper-left corner and row/column intervals in a header file)?  Depending on how small the values are,  it might be stored in less than 12mb.

Comment: I'm a gis noob and you just made my day :)

Comment: Complain to the providers for giving you a hopeless format. Use GDAL tools to recover

Comment: @Vince - post as answer?

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108456/qgis-tilemill-mapbox-how-to-downscale-grid-points-or-another-solution just not as detailed

Answer (score 1):

You could of course filter out the data points one-of-two or one-of-four, but you'd be able to retain the original information in a fraction of the original size if you convert it to a binary raster.  Lots of ways to get there, and most assume the point data is sorted (better to be sorted west-to-east in bands from north-to-south), but you can populate that grid pretty easily with a single memory allocation and some basic computational algebra.  Storing dates might be a bit trickier than numeric values, but if you only need general classes of "when" whey might pack even smaller (4-bit).  I'd recommend two "BSQ" files (single-band, they'd be the same as "BIL" and "BIP"), with
a ".hdr" to contain origin and rows/cols/cellsize information.  The [ArcGIS doc](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/BIL_BIP_and_BSQ_raster_files/009t00000010000000/) describes the process, but it's not specific to ArcGIS.